# Gradle copy resources, processResources

Tags: gradle

I am trying to copy 2 folders from my project folder into the jar.
When I use following settings Gradle copies the files inside the folders, not the folders themself:

```
processResources {
    from 'public'
    from 'data'
}
```

What I need is to have folder "projectDir/data" copyied into "my.jar/data".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `copy` spec in Gradle copies contents of a folder if the specified path in `from` is a folder.

One solution is to specify the target folder in the `jar` using the [`into`](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001741/ch01.html) [directive](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html).

```
processResources {
    from 'data'
    from 'publicFolder'
}

task data(type: Copy) {
    from 'data' into 'data'
}

task publicFolder(type: Copy) {
    from 'public' into 'public'
}
```

This will put the contents or the original folders into the folder with the same name within the jar. But as you can see, you'll need to repeat the folder names within the `into` closure.

Another workaround is to have a parent folder for these resource folders and use this parent folder in the `copy` spec.

Here's one way you could structure the resource folders:

```
<project-folder>
|
--> res
    |
    --> public
    --> data
```

Then in the `copy` spec of `processResources`, you can do the following:

```
processResources {
    from 'res'   
}
```

This will create folders `public` and `data` in the final jar file as you want.

Comment: Is it possible to say "copy from 'projectRoot' folder and only take 'data' and 'public'" folders?

Comment: Using filters for folder names somehow didn't work correctly for me. I've however edited the answer with a primary solution which doesn't involve re-arranging folders. Hope that helps. I do agree that the ideal way is to say _copy from 'projectRoot' folder and include only folders that I want_. Will post a solution to that if I get one.

Comment: Thank you for the "from into" solution. It was something I was looking for. The problem is it does not work for me. I get error "> Could not find method public() for arguments [build_akni020h40dn3k7vwmwbm63ee$_run_closure2_closure3@4d266391] on root project"

Comment: I found the solution based on your advice and the error message I got. Gradle considers those directives the name of a custom method. I edited your solution and will accept the answer once you accept the edit or otherwise specify a working solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

There is a method of 'from' that takes a closure with CopySpec.

I would recommend using this instead of either breaking up into separate tasks or restructuring your layout.

```
processResources {
    from('data') {into 'data'}
    from('publicFolder') {into 'publicFolder'}
}
```